# Calculating the probabilities of different lengths of repetitions of numbers of length 4

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to calculate the probabilities of different lengths of repetitions of X length number however I know I'm doing it incorrectly since when I add all the probabilities together they don't total to 1

e.g. 
Here is my reasoning to calculate the probabilities of the different lengths repetitions for length 4

Probability that there are 0 repeating sequences: 
e.g. WXYZ
10/10 * (9/10)^3 = 729

Probability that there is 1 repeating sequence of length 2: 
e.g XXYZ or YXXZ or YZXX
10/10 * (9/10)^2 * 1/10 * 3 = 243

Probability that there is 2 repeating sequence of length 2: 
e.g XXYY or YYXX
10/10 * 9/10 * (1/10)^2 * 2 = 18

Probability that there is a repeating sequence of length 3: 
e.g XXXY or YXXX
10/10 * 9/10 * (1/10)^2 * 2 = 18

Probability that there is a repeating sequence of length 4:
e.g XXXX
10/10 * (1/10)^2 * 3 = 1

When I add the number of outcomes I get 1009, when I should be getting a 1000.
Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh god, thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third entry in the list has a wrong count. One should not multiply by $2$, since shape XXYY is the same as shape YYXX.

Comment: Isn't WXYZ also incorrect?

Comment: @BruceTrumbo: Yes, that is also incorrect. And there is mixing of probability and counting, so there are layout problems.  And the problem is not fully defined, it is not clear whether initial $0$'s are allowed.